# Rails 4: 500 (Internal Server Error) when loading partial with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `Calendar` and a `Post` models, using shallow routes:

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :posts, shallow: true
end
```

A `calendar` `has_many` `post` and a `post` `belong_to` a `calendar`.

On `Calendars#Index`, I display all the posts of a calendar.

I am trying to update the custom `approval` attribute of a post from this very same view, using an AJAX call, so the page is not reloaded but the new value of the attribute is displayed.

In the calendar `index.html.erb` file, I have:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr id="post_row_<%= post.id%>">
    ... # Truncated for brivety
        <td class="cell_content_center post_approval_section">
      <% if post.approval == "ok" %>
        <span class="ok_green">
      <% else %>
        <span class="approval_blue" %>
      <% end %>
        <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Approve Post"></span>
        <% end %>
      </span><br/>
      <% if post.approval == "edit" %>
        <span class="edit_yellow">
      <% else %>
        <span class="approval_blue" %>
      <% end %>
        <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Require Edits"></span>
      <% end %>
      </span><br/>
      <% if post.approval == "remove" %>
        <span class="remove_red">
      <% else %>
        <span class="approval_blue" %>
      <% end %>
        <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="To Be Deleted"></span>
      <% end %>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is my `PostsController`:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in the `update.js.erb` file in the `app/views/posts` folder, I added:

```
$('#post_row_<%= j post.id %>').select.('.post_approval_section').html('<%= j render(partial: "calendar_show_approval") %>');
```

—————

**UPDATE**: I have also tried with:

```
$('#post_row_<%= j post.id %> > .post_approval_section').html('<%= j render(partial: "calendar_show_approval") %>');
```

But I get the same result in the browser and the error in the console.

—————

Finally, I have created a `_calendar_show_approval.html.erb` partial in the same `app/views/posts` folder:

```
<% if post.approval == "ok" %>
  <span class="ok_green">
<% else %>
  <span class="approval_blue" %>
<% end %>
  <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Approve Post"></span>
  <% end %>
</span><br/>
<% if post.approval == "edit" %>
  <span class="edit_yellow">
<% else %>
  <span class="approval_blue" %>
<% end %>
  <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Require Edits"></span>
<% end %>
</span><br/>
<% if post.approval == "remove" %>
  <span class="remove_red">
<% else %>
  <span class="approval_blue" %>
<% end %>
  <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="To Be Deleted"></span>
<% end %>
</span>
```

When I click on one of my three links supposed to update the `post` `approval` attribute, nothing happens in the browser and I get the following error message in the console:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/posts/38?post%5Bapproval%5D=remove 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:9665
jQuery.extend.ajax  @   jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:9216
$.rails.rails.ajax  @   jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1:94
$.rails.rails.handleRemote  @   jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1:177
(anonymous function)    @   jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1:406
jQuery.event.dispatch   @   jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:4671
elemData.handle @   jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:4339
```

—————

**UPDATE 2**: here is the content of my `log/development.log` file:

```
Started PATCH "/posts/37?post%5Bapproval%5D=ok" for ::1 at 2015-11-19 08:08:12 -0800
Processing by PostsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"approval"=>"ok"}, "id"=>"37"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35mPost Load (1.5ms)[0m  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 37]]
  [1m[36m (1.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (3.3ms)[0m  UPDATE "posts" SET "approval" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "posts"."id" = $3  [["approval", "ok"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-19 16:08:12.522940"], ["id", 37]]
  [1m[36mSQL (7.4ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "versions" ("event", "object", "whodunnit", "created_at", "object_changes", "item_id", "item_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["event", "update"], ["object", "---\nid: 37\ncalendar_id: 6\ndate: 2015-11-18 04:25:00.000000000 Z\nsubject: Subjects\nformat: Link\ncopy: Copy 2\ncreated_at: 2015-11-16 04:25:59.404072000 Z\nupdated_at: 2015-11-19 00:39:30.866318000 Z\nimage_file_name: Capture_d’écran_2015-08-25_à_19.38.59.png\nimage_content_type: image/png\nimage_file_size: 1212743\nimage_updated_at: 2015-11-16 05:35:46.273534000 Z\nshort_copy: Short Copy 2\nscore: \nfacebook: true\ntwitter: true\ninstagram: false\npinterest: false\ngoogle: false\nlinkedin: false\ntumblr: \nsnapchat: \napproval: edit\n"], ["whodunnit", "1"], ["created_at", "2015-11-19 16:08:12.522940"], ["object_changes", "---\napproval:\n- edit\n- ok\nupdated_at:\n- 2015-11-19 00:39:30.866318000 Z\n- 2015-11-19 16:08:12.522940000 Z\n"], ["item_id", 37], ["item_type", "Post"]]
  [1m[35m (12.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered posts/_approval.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered posts/update.js.erb (2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 13.2ms | ActiveRecord: 26.5ms)
```

—————

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get in `log/development.log`?

Comment: Thanks for asking @ChrisPeters. Please see the **UPDATE 2** section of my answer for the development logs. It seems like there is no error and everything is rendered properly. So I must have made a mistake in the JS then, right?

Comment: That's not the right part of the log. Your error is with `PATCH http://localhost:3000/posts/38?post%5Bapproval%5D=remove`

Comment: Well, it is the same thing: there is a button to mark post approval as "ok", another one as "edit" and a third one for "remove". I am happy to click on the remove button and copy/paste the new log, but basically, it calls the same action and renders the same partial. Let me know.

Comment: @dan-klasson is right. If the `remove` is failing, you should be looking in the log for that specifically. Is the `ok` scenario causing errors in the browser too? If not, then it matters. :)

Comment: Another thing to try is to open the Network tab in your browser console, click the button that causes the error, and inspect the request that is returning a 500 code. You should be able to "preview" it and see any errors that Rails is returning. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do I see `%` in `<span class="approval_blue" %>`?
 shouldn't it be `<span class="approval_blue" >`